# "tlsv1 alert unknown ca" when creating server with OpenSSL API

Tags: c, ssl, server, openssl

I am creating a web server with the OpenSSL API in C, everything works fine, I can access my website through a browser but when I share a link on Discord, I got this error message :
`1568:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 48`

What I want is that the Discord integration shows a preview of the link, like this : [Discord integration example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7cb0.png)

This is what I've done :

```c
#define CA_CERT_FILE     "cacert.pem"
#define SERVER_CERT_FILE "cert.pem"
#define SERVER_KEY_FILE  "key.pem"

SSL_CTX *create_context() {
    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
    if(!ctx) {
        wprintf(L"Unable to create SSL context");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL); //Tested with a callback function that return 1, still not work
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION);
    SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file(CA_CERT_FILE));

    if(!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CA_CERT_FILE, NULL)) {
        printf("SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations error!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, SERVER_CERT_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        printf("SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file error!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, SERVER_KEY_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        printf("SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file error!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
        printf("SSL_CTX_check_private_key error!\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ctx;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, SERVER_CERT_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
  ...
```

This only sets the server certificate, but not any intermediate certificates. I think one can assume that you are using a publicly issued certificate (like from Let's Encrypt) in which case there is very likely one (or more) intermediate certificates which need to send together with the server certificate so that the [TLS client can build the trust chain to the locally trusted root certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity).

If the certificate validation fails due to an inability to build the trust chain the client might generate a TLS alert like *unknown ca* and close the connection. This received TLS alert is what you currently see on the server side.

If these intermediate certificates are missing some TLS clients will work around this misconfiguration and fill in missing intermediate certificates by themselves. But this is typically only done by browsers, not by TLS stacks in programming languages like Python, Java, C, ... . So, it might be that your server works in a browser, but fails to work when accessed by a different TLS client, even if both use the same set of trusted root certificates.

The fix is to send the intermediate certificates. This can be done by having server certificate and intermediates (in that order) in the same file and using `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` instead of `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file`.

---

Apart from that it is unknown why your code asks for client certificates. Discord will very likely not be able to send you one or not one you expect, which might be a cause of additional problems. It might be that you simply copied the code from somewhere and don't understand what it is doing, but it's these lines:

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL); //Tested with a callback function that return 1, still not work
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
...
SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file(CA_CERT_FILE));
```